# C++ Classes formatting

Tags: c++, class, format

Is this generally accepted as proper formatting for C++ classes?  I've seen so many different formats for how to code classes while trying to learn them. I'm just wondering what the standard or 'normal' way of doing it is.

```
class Circle
{
private:
    double radius;
public:
    Circle()
    {
        radius = 0.0;
    }
    Circle(double r)
    {
        radius = r;
    }
    // MEMBER
    void setRadius(double r)
    {
        radius = r;
    }
    double getArea()
    {
        return 3.14159 * radius * radius;
    }
};
```

Comment: There is no one standard way to format code in C++ (or in most other languages, for that matter).  There are lots of ways to format C++ code; the only important rules are (a) make sure the code is readable and (b) make sure your formatting is consistent.

Comment: And it must match the rest of the codebase you are working in, no matter how stupid.

Comment: If it compiles correctly then pretty much it's correct form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of taste and consistency. There are many ways in which you can format not just classes, but all parts of the code in general. What's important is that the code is readable to anyone involved on your project, and follows basic guidelines in your group/workplace/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally put the members in the bottom:

```
class Circle {
public:
  Circle() {
    radius = 0.0;
  }

  Circle(double r) {
    radius = r;   
  }

  void setRadius(double r) {
    radius = r;
  }

  double getArea() {
    return 3.14159 * radius * radius;
  }

private:
  double radius;
};
```

Comment: Most places (but certainly not all) would put the opening braces of class and function definitions on a separate line as well (as he did, but you didn't).

Answer (score 1):

There is no universally preferred format, but what you show is probably
the most widely accepted.  With one exception: it's usually considered
bad form to put the function implementations in the class definition.

Comment: +1, though if you're writing a template class, you *have* to put them in there.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, you can still do template member functions outside of the class, you just have to repeat the entire template name, which is kind of annoying. But I do this quite often, in particular for templated member functions in a non-template class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard or format.

If you are working alone, do what makes it more readable for yourself - and sure, if you look at other people's code and say "Hey, that looks more readable", then feel free to assimilate their coding habits in your own.

If you are working in a team, it's best to follow some guidelines as set down by the team in general, lest you incur the wrath of the senior programmer who has spent a thousand more years in C++ than you have and evidently has a place set aside for him on God's right hand when he finally expires.  Jests aside, it makes things much easier if a team is following guidelines.

This is my personal preference, hopefully I won't get down-votes for preferences:

```
template<class T>   // template declaration if required
class myAwesomeClass
{
public:
    /*
     * Static stuff that is public goes here, oh and any type-definitions that are
     * also externally viewable
     */

private:

     /*
      * All my secret stuff
      */

protected:

     /*
      * My descendants can be decadent with this stuff, may they revel in the power
      */

public:
     /*
      * The rest of you guys get this
      */
}   // eo class myAwesomeclass, comment to determine the end of the definition
    // this can be useful if things are big!
```

Answer (score 0):

As classes are private by default the `private:` keyword after your first `{` is superfluous. The formatting that I have seen most and makes sense to me is`public:` then `protected:` then `private:` for access-specifier order.